# Not able to change URL's in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

We have been duplicating products in Magento in order to have the categories etc assigned, and then typing in new information title etc, deleting out the URL key so it saves a new one with the new product, but when we look at the product on our website is have been given the URL of the product prior to duplication and a number, why is magento not creating a new URL automatically? Plus I have then gone into the product, and a URL has not been saved I have then entered the correct URL and Magento has still not changed the URL? Someone please help!!

Answer (score 1):

Please run a reindex of 'Catalog URL Rewrite'. That can be done from the CLI or the Admin area. This will update the URL Rewrites in a database table called 'core_url_rewrite'

Good Link for Reference and Explination:
https://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-administration/664-fixing-url-rewrites-with-magento

Comment: Thanks for that but already tried it, and nothing has changed